Error using MoviePy in Streamlit: "creation of None failed because of [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
I'm encountering an issue when using MoviePy in my Streamlit application. The error message I'm receiving is:
MoviePy Error: creation of None failed because of the following error:
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified. 
This error can be due to the fact that ImageMagick is not installed on your computer, or (for Windows users) that you didn't specify the path to the ImageMagick binary in file conf.py, or that the path you specified is incorrect.    

I've tried specifying the path to the ImageMagick binary in MoviePy's conf.py file, but it doesn't seem to resolve the issue. How can I address this problem, especially if I plan to deploy my Streamlit application?
Error Image:

I have tried using local path its working but can't deploy it right.
